# Servicestack json client post method not deserialzing correctly

Tags: servicestack

I'm having trouble with the ServiceStack Json client not deserialzing my results when I use POST.  The get methods have no problems deserialzing the response into a UserCredentials object but when I use POST method, it returns an object with all null properties.  If I change the type passed to the Post method to a dictionary I can see that it is getting the right results, and I can see the rest call succeeds at the http level from Fiddler.

```
   public UserCredentials Login(string uname, string pwd)
    {
        var url = "/login";
        //note that I have to send a dictionary because if I sent a Login Object with username and password it erronously sends {Login:} in the raw request body instead of {"Uname":uname, "Password":password}

        var login = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Uname", uname }, { "Password", pwd } };
        var result = client.Post<UserCredentials>(url, login);

        return result;

    }
```

Here's the response (which is the correct and expected http response from the server)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 14 Mar 2013 12:55:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 49

{"Uid":1,"Hash":"SomeHash"}
```

And here is the UserCredentials class

```
  public class UserCredentials
  {
    public long Uid;
    public string Hash;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary instead of an instance of UserCredentials?

Comment: I tried sending User credentials but it errored by sending {Login:} rather than {Uname:"foo",Password:"bar"}.  I would prefer to send UserCredentials but I couldn't get it to work.  Is there a suggested way to do so that would make it work?

Comment: I think you will have to post the entire code if none of these answers have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to make Uid and Hash public properties instead of public fields. Though, I'm not sure how your GET requests are deserializing properly if this is the case.

```
public class UserCredentials
{
    public long Uid {get; set;}
    public string Hash {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Yep, needs to be public fields or it needs to set: `JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;` on Application start.

Answer (score 1):

What does your ServiceStack server side code look like? Doing something like below on the server should allow you to use JsonServiceClient like this:

Call to LoginService:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://url.com/login");
var response = client.Post<LoginResponse>(new Login() {Uname = "username", Password = "secret"});
var credentials = response.Credentials;
```

LoginService Implementation:

```
public class Login : IReturn<LoginResponse>
{
    public string Uname { get; set; }
    public string Pasword { get; set; }
}

public class UserCredentials
{
    public long Uid {get; set;}
    public string Hash {get; set;}
}

public class LoginResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public LoginResponse()
    {
        this.ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
    }

    public UserCredentials UserCredentials { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class LoginService : Service
{
    public LoginResponse Post(Login request)
    {
        //Code to Get UserCredentials
        return new LoginResponse {UserCredentials = new UserCredentials()};
    }
}
```

Comment: The server side code returns a UserCredentials object as shown in the raw http response output, I'm using WebApi instead of servicestack on the server side.

Comment: Oh, you might want to tag this question with WebApi. Is your WebApi controller's Post method binding model/parameters correctly? It sounds like the 'wire format' of the JsonServiceClient request is not what WebApi expects (unless you use a Dictionary). I'm not exactly sure how the WebApi model binder works.

Comment: The web api is responding correctly and is working fine.  This seems to have the same behaviour no matter the server.  The error I'm seeing is in the client deserializing the response rather than in the server sending the right output

Comment: the web api is responding with a 200 and the correct UserCredentials object as shown in the raw output sample above.